# Notification when QDockWidget's tab is clicked?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qmainwindow, qdockwidget

I need to execute a block of code when the user clicks on the tab of a tabbified QDockWidget. So far I've been doing this via a hack using the "visibilityChanged" event but this is now causing issues (for example, if I have several tabbified dock widgets and I drag one out so that it is floating, the tabbified one underneath will fire its "visibilityChanged" event which I will mistakenly interpret as the user clicking the tab). How can I receive proper notification when a user clicks on a QDockWidgets' tab? I've experimented with the "focusInEvent" of QDockWidget but it doesn't seem to fire when the tab is clicked.

Comment: When a partitioned item is dragged, the click will also be triggered, is it okay for that to happen?, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'm afraid the click event is of no help here. I just need to be notified when a user clicks on the tab.

Comment: his phrase is contradictory, on the one hand it indicates that the clicked event will not be useful and on the other hand you want to be notified of the clicked. You want potatoes but you do not want the potato.

Comment: If I handle the "mousePressEvent" in my QDockWidget, the event is not raised when the user selects the tab. Ergo it does not provide notification of when the tab is clicked and is not useful for this case.

Comment: Why do you assume that I use that method? I use another method and it is launched when the tab is pressed. :)

Comment: Can you please tell me what the method is that is launched when the tab is pressed? Note: I'm using PyQt 4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `tabifyDockWidget()` method `QMainWindow` creates a `QTabBar`, this is not directly accessible but using `findChild()` you can get it, and then use the `tabBarClicked` signal

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        first_dock = None

        for i in range(10):
            dock = QtGui.QDockWidget("title {}".format(i), self)
            dock.setWidget(QtGui.QTextEdit()) # testing
            self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, dock)
            if first_dock:
                self.tabifyDockWidget(first_dock, dock)
            else:
                first_dock = dock
                dock.raise_()

        tabbar = self.findChild(QtGui.QTabBar, "")
        tabbar.tabBarClicked.connect(self.onTabBarClicked)

    def onTabBarClicked(self, index):
        tabbar = self.sender()
        text = tabbar.tabText(index)
        print("index={}, text={}".format(index, text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```